# react-bootstrap-table-toolkit Search Import Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I wanted to use `React Bootstrap Table` in my project and I'm getting the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined at Object../node_modules/react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit/lib/src/search/SearchBar.js

here is the following import which are referred from their [official website](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Table%20Search&selectedStory=Basic%20Search%20Table&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel).

```js
import ToolkitProvider, {Search} from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';

const {SearchBar} = Search;
```

where search can not be found from this import.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an easy fix, I resolved this issue by changing the import

from

```js
import ToolkitProvider, {Search} from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';
```

to

```js
import ToolkitProvider, {Search} from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit/dist/react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';
```

Comment: nailed it mrrowley, do you know why the normal import doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The fix isnt still in place; change your import pointing to the .min file of toolkit

replace this

**import ToolkitProvider, { CSVExport } from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";**

with this

**import ToolkitProvider , { CSVExport } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit/dist/react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit.min'**